# How to change PATH in windows OS via cmd

Tags: variables, path, cmd, windows-vista

I am trying to add a path, in `PATH` variable. I run `cmd.exe` as administrator and used

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin"
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin"
```

I then restarted my computer, but if I type `path` I don't see the paths that I set there. Note that with the exact same way I was able to set some other directories on `PATH`.

Any idea on what might be wrong?

Comment: This probably belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: You say "My directory" - do you see EITHER of the two directories, or do you ony see `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`

Comment: @Magoo: Thank's for your comment. You mean if I see both directories when I type `path`? When I type `path` I don't see them. But generaly they exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
"My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" > "Path".
```

Comment: That was the first thing to do(run as administrator), but it seems that it didn't work. That's why I moved to `cmd`...

Answer (score 1):

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin"
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin"
```

Should first set PATH to "%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin" and then to "%PATH%;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin", so the second `setx` overrides the first because `setx` does not set the variable in the current or existing CMD sessions - only new ones.

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin"
```

theoretically should set `PATH` with those two directories appended - for future sessions.

You can check by simply starting a new session and executing a

```
path
```

command.

If the change doesn't survive a reboot, then some other process is resetting it.

If the change doesn't occur at all, then there's something mighty fishy going on. Possibly a typo...

I'd try setting some other variable as a test, say `mypath`.

You can delete a variable using

```
setx mypath ""
```

Googling for `PATH EDITOR` may be useful...

Comment: Well, it didn't survive a reboot...I checked for typos, but there aren't any. I used the paths just as they were shown on explorer.

Comment: Your anti-malware/security or AV software is probably interfering with the change.

Comment: Agree - without a clear statement of whether the change was effective in the first instance or not, we're making blind guesses.